# menubar disabled by frame

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Trying to teach myself PyQt5, so I'm guessing I am just not adding something in.  But I currently have a menu bar at the top of the window and am wanting to add a frame underneath, but doing so makes the menu bar inaccessible.  Without the frame the menu bar works just fine.  How do I fix this?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QFrame, QAction, qApp, QStackedWidget, QWidget, QListWidget, QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
import sys


class CharManMain(QMainWindow):

   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()

       self.initUI()


   def initUI(self):
       '''initiates application UI'''

       exitAct = QAction('&Exit', self)
       exitAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
       exitAct.setStatusTip('Exit Application')
       exitAct.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

       newAct = QAction('&New', self)
       newAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+N')
       newAct.setStatusTip('Create a New character')

       openAct = QAction('&Open', self)
       openAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
       openAct.setStatusTip('Open a saved character')

       statusbar = self.statusBar()

       menubar = self.menuBar()
       fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
       characterMenu = menubar.addMenu('Characters')

       fileMenu.addAction(newAct)
       fileMenu.addAction(openAct)
       fileMenu.addAction(exitAct)

       baseFrame = QFrame(self)

       vbox = QVBoxLayout()
       vbox.addWidget(menubar)
       vbox.addWidget(baseFrame)
       vbox.addWidget(statusbar)

       self.setLayout(vbox)     

       self.setWindowTitle('Character Manager v0.01')
       self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   charMain = CharManMain()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QMainWindow.setCentralWidget(widget)

Sets the given widget to be the main window’s central widget.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QFrame, QAction, qApp, 
                             QStackedWidget, QWidget, QListWidget, QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class CharManMain(QMainWindow):  

   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()

       self.initUI()


   def initUI(self):
       '''initiates application UI'''

       exitAct = QAction('&Exit', self)
       exitAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
       exitAct.setStatusTip('Exit Application')
       exitAct.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

       newAct = QAction('&New', self)
       newAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+N')
       newAct.setStatusTip('Create a New character')

       openAct = QAction('&Open', self)
       openAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
       openAct.setStatusTip('Open a saved character')

       statusbar = self.statusBar()

       menubar = self.menuBar()
       fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
       characterMenu = menubar.addMenu('Characters')

       fileMenu.addAction(newAct)
       fileMenu.addAction(openAct)
       fileMenu.addAction(exitAct)

       baseFrame = QFrame()                # --- (self)
       self.setCentralWidget(baseFrame)    # +++         <-----

       ### ---
       #vbox = QVBoxLayout()
       #vbox.addWidget(menubar)
       #vbox.addWidget(baseFrame)
       #vbox.addWidget(statusbar)
       #self.setLayout(vbox)     

       self.setWindowTitle('Character Manager v0.01')
       self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   charMain = CharManMain()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: I figured it was something simple.  Thank you.